# Create nuget package that only contains msbuild.targets

Tags: .net, msbuild, nuget

I'm trying to create a nuget package that only contains MSBuild *.targets files. I can create a C# class library and add my targets file, but I don't need the overhead of a C# build process.  Is there a way to author a nuget package that only contains static content or build files?

I've seen answers that suggest just having a raw nuspec file and use `nuget pack` to create the package. I would like to use `dotnet pack` if it is possible but it doesn't seem to support nuspec files directly.  Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [page](https://github.com/microsoft/MSBuildSdks/blob/main/src/NoTargets/README.md) lists  targets for use in various (non-typical) build scenarios.  The `Microsoft.Build.NoTargets`...

> Supports utility projects that do not compile an assembly.

Which sounded exactly like what I want.  If you look at this [page](https://github.com/microsoft/MSBuildSdks/tree/main/src/NoTargets), it provides more detail on exactly what this Project Sdk does, which is basically copy files @(FilesToCopy) to the $(OutDir) directory.

I didn't really want that, but... I created a project, my-project, with the following file structure.

```
my-project   # base project folder
|-- PackageLayout
|   |-- buildTransitive
|   |   |-- my-project.props
|   |   |-- my-project.targets
|   |-- icon.png
|   |-- README.md
|-- my-project.msbuildproj
```

The PackageLayout directory are the files and layout I want in my nuget package. The my-project.msbuildproj file is where I define all the package metadata, PackageId, PackageVersion, etc.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.Build.NoTargets/3.7.56">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard1.0</TargetFramework>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    
    <!-- Don't warn about no binaries, there aren't supposed to be any -->
    <NoWarn>NU5128</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Package metadata -->
    <PackageId>my-project</PackageId>
    <PackageVersion>1.0.0</PackageVersion>
    <DevelopmentDependency>true</DevelopmentDependency>
    <IsTool>true</IsTool>

    <PackageReadmeFile>README.md</PackageReadmeFile>
    <PackageIcon>icon.png</PackageIcon>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!--
    * Display project root files in the project         : `Include="*"`
      * But don't include them in the nuget package     : `Pack="false"`
      * Exclude the msbuildproj file as it is displayed
        at the project level                            : `Exclude="$(MSBuildProjectFile)"`
    -->
    <None Include="*" Pack="false" Exclude="$(MSBuildProjectFile)"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!--
    Include everything in the PackageLayout directory in the package
    and maintain the same directory structure (but from the package
    root)
    -->
    <None Include="PackageLayout\**\*" Pack="true" PackagePath="\" />

    <!--
    Anything in buildTransitive directory, also pack in the build directory
    for backwards compatability.
    
    https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/Allow-package%2d%2dauthors-to-define-build-assets-transitive-behavior
    -->
    <None Include="PackageLayout\buildTransitive\**\*" Pack="true" PackagePath="build\" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

If I run `dotnet build` on this project it produces `my-project.1.0.0.nupkg` in the $(OutDir) with the correct icon.png, readme and targets/props files.